# Proper way to Map Objects with Method in C# that includes Conditionals

Tags: c#

I have the following object with a method called ShouldShow()

```
 public class Animal {

   public bool ShouldShow()
   ...
 }
```

I have a list of said animals

```
List<Animal> animalList
```

I want to extract only the animal objects that return true on the boolean `ShouldShow()`.

I did the following:

```
List<Animal> availableAnimals =  animalList.Select(a => a.ShouldShow()).ToList()
```

This will not work because `ShouldShow` returns a boolean. How should I change the call so that it checks the `ShouldShow` and returns the Object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Where` instead of `Select`

```
List<Animal> availableAnimals = animalList.Where(a => a.ShouldShow()).ToList()
```

Comment: OH haha. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!